# How to determine which sets are open in a topology?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Given $A_n = \{n, n+1, \dots\} , n \in \mathbb{N} $ and $\tau = \{ \emptyset, A_1, A_2, \dots \} $, I would like to determine which sets are open in $(\mathbb{N}, \tau) $

By definition: $A_n$ is open and any intersection/union of finitely/infinitely many $A_n$ is also open. Furthermore: $A_n$ is infinite, ${A_n}^C$ is finite.

However this does not tell or really help me deciding, what are any other open/closed sets regarding this topology? For example: Is set of odd/even numbers open? What about an arbitrary set? etc.

It seems I am missing a very basic property of topologies. Therefore how does one approach above problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This answer is based on a misreading of the question. I read the question as asking about the topology *generated by* $\{A_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ - equivalently, asking to prove that that that set is already a topology.

As noted above, given that the OP already is told that $\{A_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is a topology, their question does boil down to just understanding how a topology describes open sets (namely, that the topology *is exactly* the set of open sets).

However, I suspect that the OP may be confused about *why* this family is a topology on $\mathbb{N}$. Since I think my (misinformed) answer may be useful to them with respect to this, I've left it up (with minor changes).

---

---

A set with the property that its complement is finite is called **cofinite**. For example, all the $A_i$s above are cofinite.

Here are a couple hints towards showing that the set of even numbers is *not* open in the above sense:

- Show that the union of aritrarily many cofinite sets is cofinite. *(HINT: any set containing a cofinite set is cofinite ...)*
- Show that the intersection of finitely many cofinite sets is cofinite. *(HINT: think about the complement of a finite intersection of cofinite sets - remember that the complement of an intersection is the union of the complements ...)*
- Conclude that every open set (in the sense above) is cofinite.

---

Note that the above does *not* fully characterize the open sets (again, in the sense of your question). For example, the set of all numbers except $3$ and $17$ is cofinite; is it open?

- Show that if $B$ is open in the sense above, and $b\in B$ and $c>b$, then $c\in B$.
- Use the above to give a complete characterization of the open sets in the sense above.

Answer (score 6):

$\tau$ is already a topology on $\mathbb{N}$. The open sets are precisely $\emptyset$ and $A_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Perhaps you meant to ask how to verify that $\tau$ is a topology.
Notice that $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore, $$\bigcup_{i \in S} A_i = A_{\min S} \in \tau$$

for every $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

Also, $$\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_{i} = A_n \in \tau$$
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We have $\phi \in \tau$ and $\mathbb{N} = A_1 \in \tau$. We conclude that $\tau$ is a topology.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the word 'topology' is the collection of all open sets. Therefore, if someone tells you that the topology is
$$\tau=\{\emptyset, A_1,A_2,\dots\}$$
then this is precisely the collection of all open sets. There are no others. You can check that this is indeed a topology, i.e., the union open sets is open (that is, a member of the set $\tau$), etc.